# How do I check if a double with decimals is divisible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, floating-point, double

I'm trying to test if a number is cleanly divisible (no remainders) by another. If I compare it against an int, it works correctly:

```
NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = // a double goes here

// round to 3 decimal points to avoid floating point weirdness
timeElapsed = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f",timeElapsed] doubleValue];
```

and then

```
// This works correctly

if (fmod(timeElapsed, 1) == 0) {
           NSLog(@"is divisible");
 }
```

But if I compare it with a decimal, it fails, firing only intermittedly:

```
// This does NOT work correctly

if (fmod(timeElapsed, .1) == 0) {
            NSLog(@"is divisible");     
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** After reading the answer and great comments below, I've come to the conclusion that this whole approach is a bad idea. There's no guarentee of being able to generate specific time intervals. It's probably better just to create seperate timers instead listening to one "main" timer.

Comment: what exactly does not work for you ?

Comment: @giorashc If, for example, `timeElapsed` is 3.400, it should pass the test because it should be cleanly divisible by `.1`. But it does not.

Comment: Paul R has a very good point on this issue. From what I understand you are trying to do something every 0.1 sec ?

Comment: @giorashc Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an awful approach. Floating point numbers can't be trusted. Give each element its own timer so you don't have to listen to specific numbers.

Answer (score 3):

In general floating point numbers are not exactly representable, since you only have a finite number of bits with which to represent them (32 or 64 typically). You should therefore never test for exact equality, but instead test to within an acceptably small tolerance, e.g.

```
if (fabs(fmod(timeElapsed, .1)) < SOME_SMALL_VALUE) {
    NSLog(@"is divisible");     
}
```

It's a good idea to read the [Goldberg paper on floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) if you're going to be writing any serious numerical code.

Comment: Maybe I should have added this to my example, but I'm rounding the `timeElapsed` to 3 decimal points before I compare it.

Comment: If NSTimeInterval is a floating point value then it doesn't matter whether you round it or not.

Comment: A common value to use for "SOME_SMALL_VALUE" is FLT_EPSILON. You can see the effect that Paul is discussing if you print out the value of fmod(timeElapsed). 0.1 cannot be expressed precisely in binary, so it's not possible to apply fmod() to it and get precise values. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.1+to+binary

Comment: If you need precise decimal math, you have to use `NSDecimalNumber`, but it's better usually to do approximate floating point math as Paul suggests.

Comment: If the floating point stuff seems too complicated, you can multiple both values by 1000, round them off to an integer, and use mod to get 3 decimal places of precision.

Comment: @RobNapier I tried logging the value of `fmod(timeElapsed, .1)`. It's always either `0.100000` or `0.000000`.

Comment: Print it to more decimal places. Though as I think about it, Marcus's suggestion is better for several reasons, since the mod operation could easily wind up being on the "wrong side" (so instead of being very close to zero, it could be very close to the divisor). Yeah; multiply, convert to int and then mod.

Comment: What you see is not always what you get :)

Comment: @yourfriendzak: when you log a floating point value, the value is rounded prior to display, so you're not seeing the actual value of the variable.

Comment: `remainder(timeElapsed, .1) < FLT_EPSILON` that works as expected.

Comment: The `fabs` is a waste of time because `fmod` is defined to return a value with the same sign as its first argument, and elapsed time should never be negative. Second, `SOME_SMALL_VALUE` is not specified, so this answer is incomplete. A previous comment suggests using `FLT_EPSILON`, but that fails as soon as elapsed time exceeds 2 seconds: The ULP of numbers 2 and up is greater than `FLT_EPSILON`, so the test will return false for all numbers near multiples of .1 other than exact multiples such as 2.5 and 3, even supposing the system actually measured time with a granularity of `FLT_EPSILON`.

Comment: This code does not test whether a number is near a multiple of .1, it tests whether a number is near a multiple of `.1`, that is, the double that is nearest .1.

Comment: Assuming that the code will be testing with the goal of “firing” every tenth of a second, one might simply want to ask whether the elapsed time exceeds .1 seconds. If so, fire and reset the base time to the current time. That avoids problems of testing for multiples of .1. Also, it ought to be specified what to do if multiple intervals pass before the code is able to fire—if .2 or 2000 seconds have passed instead of .1 second, do you want to fire once or multiple times? Other code might be recommended in light of a complete specification of desired behavior.

Comment: Note that the premise of testing whether elapsed time is a multiple of .1 seconds is flawed. User code in iOS cannot control the system entirely; it will not always be running. The operating system provides no guarantee that certain user code will be running when those tenth-of-second multiples come: There are device interrupts, other processes, even other threads in the current process. So if you test for being near a multiple of .1 seconds, your code might miss its opportunity, repeatedly. It might run when the elapsed time is .15, .21, and .37 seconds, never near .1, .2, and .3…

Comment: … The above is why it may be better to test “Has it been more than .1 seconds since the last time I fired?” rather than “Has it been a multiple of .1 seconds since I started measuring?”

Comment: Oops, a correction: Comparing with `FLT_EPSILON` will not fail as described at 2. Comparing with `DBL_EPSILON` would fail at 2, since the type is `double`. `FLT_EPSILON` is essentially an unrelated value but will fail similarly unless the time being used has sub-microsecond resolution.

Comment: Per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html), NSTimeInterval provides sub-millisecond precision.

Comment: @EricPostpischil interesting comments. The point of this issue is that I'm creating a single timer which spawns sub-events. Each sub-event is designed to listen to the main timer and fire themselves each time their designated increment is reached (once per seconds, once per ms, etc). The purpose of the sub-events is to act as a convenience method so other objects can subscribe to the events. The reason I'm not generating a separate timer for every event is that I want the simplicity and control of a single timer controlling all sub-events.

Comment: Someone delete my edits. I wanted to mark this answer as correct but it needs a brief summary of the discussion and one I added got delete mysteriously. So if you get a chance, Paul R, write a sentence or too summarizing and I'll give this answer the green check.

Comment: @yourfriendzak: no problem - I'm not sure exactly what else is needed but feel free to take whatever you want from the above answer and comments, add it to your own answer and make that the "accepted" answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform a task after 0.1 seconds repeatedly use NSTimer :

```
NSTimer *timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
            target:self
            selector:@selector(yourMethod:)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:YES];
```

To stop the timer invoke :

```
[timer invalidate];
```

Comment: NSTimer might be the best approach, but there's a caveat, from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html): `If a timer’s firing time occurs during a long callout or while the run loop is in a mode that is not monitoring the timer, the timer does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual time at which the timer fires potentially can be a significant period of time after the scheduled firing time.` You'll have the same problem with your current method anyway.